# How prove $\dfrac{|AB|}{|AC|}\le\sqrt{2}+1$

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

in $\Delta ABC$ if the $AD\perp BC$,$D\in BC$,and such $$|BC|=2|AD|$$
show that
$$\dfrac{|AB|}{|AC|}\le\sqrt{2}+1$$
[image]

since
$$\cot{B}+\cot{C}=\dfrac{BD}{AD}+\dfrac{CD}{AD}=2$$
so
$$\dfrac{AB}{AC}=\dfrac{\sin{C}}{\sin{B}}$$

Comment: Have you tried Stewart's theorem?

Comment: I think use stewart's then it's ugly

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an algebra problem in fact, and I misled myself into thinking of Stewart's theorem at first.  In fact if we let the length of $AD$ be 1 and $BC$ be 2 it becomes equivalent to trying to maximise an expression like $\frac{x^2+1}{(2-x)^2+1}$ where $x$ varies between $0$ and $2$  and since the numerator increases while the denominator decreases as $x$ increases it suffices to let $x=2$ giving a bound of $\sqrt{5}$ which is smaller than the given bound.  I do not know if there is another method that gives $\sqrt{2}+1$ though.

Comment: I've checked my answer compared with yours and the other one and I don't understand the negatives. Not for you, but I think some negatives are worth an explanation.

Comment: Well for one you did not give a reason why one only needs to consider the worst cases, because it might be the case that some value in between gives a better bound, and that is not immediately obvious unless one uses some argument to justify why the extreme value would occur at the endpoint(s)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, you confirm what I was thinking of this. Anyway, we all can see many answers offer a hint, not a direct answer and mine was intended to be that. I suppose I have to write too " HINT" or something.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I must point out that the picture is wrongly drawn. The reason is if AB is shorter than AC, the LHS of the inequality-to-be-proved is less than 1 and obviously is less than $\sqrt 2 + 1$, the RHS. This means there is nothing to be proved. Therefore, we must have $AB \ge AC$ ….. (1).

[image]

If we let $AD = 1$ and $DC = x$ for some x greater 0, then $BD = 2 – x$ and $AC = \sqrt {1 + x^2}$.

(1) implies $\sqrt {(2 – x)^2 + 1} \ge \sqrt {1 + x^2}$.

After simplifying, we arrive at the first conclusion --- $0 \le x \le 1$. Then, $AC_{min} = 1$ ….. (2).

After some simplification. the inequality-to-be-proved is equivalent to $\sqrt 2 AC \ge BC’$.

It will be true if we can prove $\sqrt 2AC \ge \sqrt 2 AC_{min} \ge BC’_{max} \ge BC’$.

Or simply, $\sqrt 2 AC_{min} \ge BC’_{max}$ …. (*)

From (2), LHS = $\sqrt 2$ …. (3)

RHS = Max $[\sqrt {(2 – x)^2 + 1} - \sqrt {1 + x^2}] = Max[\sqrt {(2 – x)^2 + 1}] – Min [\sqrt {1 + x^2}] = ....$

$ =\sqrt 5 – 1$ …. (4)

(*) is true by comparing (3) and (4).

Answer (score 0):

In the standard notation $AD=\frac{a}{2}$ and let $\frac{c}{b}=x$.

Thus, $$\frac{a^2}{4}=S_{\Delta ABC}$$ or
$$\frac{a^2}{4}=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2)-a^4-b^4-c^4}$$ or
$$2a^4-2(b^2+c^2)a^2+b^4+c^4-2b^2c^2=0,$$ which gives
$$(b^2+c^2)^2-2(b^4+c^4-2b^2c^2)\geq0$$ or
$$c^4-6b^2c^2+b^4\leq0$$ or
$$x^4-6x^2+1\leq0$$ or
$$3-\sqrt2\leq x^2\leq3+2\sqrt2$$ or
$$\sqrt2-1\leq x\leq1+\sqrt2,$$ which gives
$$\frac{AB}{AC}\leq1+\sqrt2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Taking $|AC| = 1$, we have
$$|AD| = \sin C = \frac12|BC| \qquad |CD|=\cos C \quad\text{(as a signed length)}$$
so that
$$\begin{align}
|AB|^2 &= |AD|^2+|BD|^2 = |AD|^2+\left(|BC|-|CD|\right)^2 \\[4pt]
&= \sin^2C + (2\sin C-\cos C) \\[4pt]
&= 1-4\sin C\cos C+4\sin^2 C \\[4pt]
&= 1-2\sin 2C+2(1-\cos2C) \\[4pt]
&= 3-2(\sin 2C+\cos2C) \\[4pt]
&= 3-2\sqrt{2}\cos(2C-\pi/4)
\end{align}$$
This value is clearly maximized with the cosine is $-1$ (that is, when $C= 5\pi/8$), where we have
$$|AB|^2 = 3 + 2 \sqrt{2} = \left(\;1 + \sqrt{2}\;\right)^2$$
proving the result. $\square$

---

Because we can write (spontaneously changing $C$ to $\theta$)
$$|AB|^2 = 1^2 + \sqrt{2}^2 - 2 \cdot 1 \cdot \sqrt{2}\cdot\cos(2\theta-\pi/4)$$
à la the Law of Cosines, the general scenario can be *illustrated* (though not (yet?) properly *explained*) thusly:

[image]

with this optimal state:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think you have only to check the worst of the cases, so is, prove that $\sqrt{5}\le\sqrt 2 +1$

Comment: Please, for the clickers, can you explain a little more why did you downvote a correct answer?